# C# calculator, can't get the mathematical operators to come up in the text box

Tags: c#, calculator

I got the calculator to function correctly but decided that the code was far too messy and I needed to tidy it up and find the best practice which I thought I found looking at some videos on youtube.

Unfortunately now I can't get the operators to display on the screen with this new method (an example would be if I press '6' the number 6 will come up but then if I press '+' nothing will happen and if I can't insert the operator then I can't check if the equal button is working)

Any help would be much appreciated the code is below.

```
Double value = 0;
String operation = "";
//bool op_pressed = false;

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button.Text;
}

public void op_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    operation = button.Text;
    value = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    //op_pressed = true;
}

public void ClearClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
}

private void EqualClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(operation)
    {
        case "+":
            textBox1.Text = (value + Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "-":
            textBox1.Text = (value - Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
            break;
        case "/":
            textBox1.Text = (value / Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
            break;  
        case "*":
            textBox1.Text = (value * Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
            break;  
        default:
            break;
    }
    //op_pressed = false;
}
```

Comment: I assume your operators subscribe to the op_click event. That event never changes the value of the text box.

Comment: Also, please don't repost just to add additional info. That's what the edit button is for.

Comment: Your question has most of the same flaws it had when you [previously posted it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401950/i-have-created-a-c-sharp-calculator-and-tried-to-clean-up-the-code-from-a-versio). The code example is not a [mcve], and your claim that "nothing happens" when the operator button is clicked is not specific enough. Surely _something_ happens. For example, you claimed (previously) that the event handler was subscribed. If that's true, then your event handler would be called. That's something. Don't delete your post again. Edit it so that it's a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Your "op_click" method is not adding the operator to the textbox1.text. That is why its not displaying.